# Avoid full page reload when changing HTML in Ionic

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, webpack, refresh, reload

In Ionic, when you change only your .scss files, they get compiled and injected to the current page of the app without having to reload the whole project. That's awesome and improves the workflow a lot.

However, if you change any HTML file, the app ***does*** get reloaded. The result is that either the app resets to the root page or you get an error for trying to go directly to a nested page. That's a problem if you're working in a page that is somewhat deep in the navigation hierarchy. You can be working there for hours. The clicks to get to that page again just to see some tiny update and continue working becomes tedious.

Can we achieve the same seamless updates like with the .scss files? I understand that can be implications with the Angular side of the HTML, I think that because of that, seamless updates aren't available with javascript neither. But in that case we can always force the reload I guess.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I think that is why the feature is called live reload;/ but yeah would be nice if there would be a better way

Answer (score 1):

```
ionic serve –-nolivereload
```

As mentioned in http://ionicn.com/docs/cli/test.html the command above should do what you want

---

**Update after understanding the question correctly:**

As a workaround you can set the Ah ok, sorry. What you can do as a workaround is to set the current component you are working on as the rootpage:

```
this.rootPage = WorkingComponent;
```

Then you will start there after the reload. But obviously thats not very comfortable for a longer time.

Comment: Thanks for your answer Yannick, however I think I didn't explain myself well. I **do** want the live-reload feature, but in a manner that doesn't force the whole project to refresh. We already have this mode when changing only SASS files. They get injected in the current state of the app without reloading the browser. My question is about how to achieve the same but with HTML files. By the way, that link looks pretty dated, it's for v1. The CLI option `--nolivereload` it's depreciated, the recommended one now is `--no-livereload`. Thanks anyway for your help :)

Comment: Ah ok sorry. I'll update my question for a workaround. Maybe it helps until a proper solution is found.

Comment: Well, this could do it, but only if the state of the current page does not depend in previous interactions. For example, simple case: a item detail page usually depends on the item itself being passed from the previous (item list) page. But this workaround is kinda smart, I guess I could temporarily mock the state, so it's better than nothing. Thank you, Yannick.

Comment: Yeah I know what you mean. But I'm glad that helps you until a better solution is found.